# ComponentDidMount is called after render throwing me map of undefined error

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm playing with the React lifecycle component,And when im trying to use ComponentdidMount it is throwing me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Please help me:
    api:
        function getRegionsData() {
        const header = {
            headers: {
                "tokenid": localStorage.getItem('token'),
                "username": localStorage.getItem('username'),
            }
        };
        const url = baseurl + '/getStatesDistrictsTalukasAndVillages';
        console.log(url);
        return axios.get(url,header).then(data =>data.data.Message);

```
MYJS.js:
import {getRegionsData} from '../../../Api';

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            regionsData:[]
        }
    }

    regions(){
        getRegionsData().then((regionsData)=>{
            this.setState({regionsData})
        })
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.regions();
    }

    render(){
        const {regionsData} =this.state;
        console.log(regionsData);
        return(
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <form ref="userForm" className="demoform">
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                {/*<span className="input-group-addon"><img src={'img/user.png'}/></span>*/}
                                <label>Name</label> <input type="text" className="form-control" ref="name"
                                                           placeholder="Name" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <select>
                                    <option>India</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <select>
                                    <option>India</option>
                                    {regionsData.States.map((state, stateId)=>{
                                        return (
                                            <option key={ stateId } value={state.statesId}>{state.statesName}</option> )
                                    })}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're getting this error after your componentDidMount function is being called, then it's likely that `regionsData.States` is not actually an array in the data you're receiving. Is that the case or is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are trying to map undefined object key. We cant know whats your response data like. You define regionsData as an array but you are doing this "regionsData.States.map" so regionsData array or object?, set your initial state "regionsData :{states: []}" or do this "regionsData.map".

Comment: then set your initial state like that, your initial regionsData is array for this code and trying to map an undefined array in undefined object. componentDidMount called after render method so render throwing an error because you didnt set new data in "regionsData".

Comment: sorry my falut, declaring object as Array.. Got the error point :-)